# Given a subject and an object, what methods can i use to inference a possible verb?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, nlp-question-answering

Given a subject A and an object B, for example, A is "Peter", B is "iPhone", Peter can be 'playing' or 'using' iPhone, the verb varies depending on the context, in this case, what kinds of method can I use to inference a possible verb?

I assume a model, which can be BERT or other models, learns the correlation between subjects, verbs, and objects through a given corpus, but I don't really know about NLP. I am expecting some off-the-shell models, or models that can be used through simple fine-tuning.

Answer (score 0):

Pretrained language models such as BERT can be used for this task. For your example, you can give BERT an input such as *Peter [MASK] an iPhone* and let BERT completes the masked tokens. Language models like BERT were pretrained to predict such masked tokens on massive amounts of text, so tasks like this are a perfect fit for them *without any fine-tuning*. Several drawbacks I can think of:

1. You have to manually specify the number of masked tokens between the subject and the object. For instance, the example above cannot result in *Peter is buying an iPhone* because there is only one masked token whereas the result has 2 tokens between *Peter* and *an iPhone*.
2. Related to the previous one, pretrained language models usually tokenize their input into subwords. For example, the word *buying* may be tokenized into *__buy* and *ing* where __ marks the start of a word. So, you can never get *buying* as the prediction if your template only has one masked token.
3. There's no way to guarantee that the predicted tokens will always correspond to a verb. You can construct the template such that the masked tokens are much more likely to correspond to a verb e.g., *Peter is [MASK] an iPhone* but there is always a risk of wrong predictions due to the probabilistic nature of pretrained language models.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The drawbacks you mentioned are actually something I've never thought about. I raised this question to seek a way of finding verbs that semantically connect a subject and an object, I expect to get the return of a list that contains verbs and their probabilities, so that I can build a vector to support the task of action detection in a multimodel view. I will do some experiments with BERT and try to construct a template, i assume there will be a method to deal with the voice of the verb ^_^